# HTTP Request fails when using the same parameters and the same environment

Tags: http

I'm trying to fetch data from a website (https://gesetze.berlin.de/bsbe/search). Using Mozilla, I've taken a look at the network analysis. Usually, I'm just messing around with the parameters of the POST-Request to see how I might influence the response of the server. But when I simply re-send the request (***making no changes at all***), I'm getting HTTP-response 500. The server answer states as message: security_notAuthenticated.

Can anyone explain that behaviour? The request is done by the same PC, the same browser in the same session, and there is no login function on that website. Pictures shown below.

[Picture 1 - Code 200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGi4N.png)

[Picture 2 - Code 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42kWy.png)

Comment: Perhaps the CSRF token is valid for only one request?

Comment: Checked that already, when clicking on "search" at the website, the same CSRF-Token is used multiple times

Comment: In the first screenshot you can see that your browser includes a Cookie header, in the second it does not.

Comment: Already checked that. In the second picture, you can see a scroll bar at the HTTP-Headers section. Scrolling down reveals the cookie is in the header, although it is pretty strange that the response always contains a new cookie.

Comment: Ok, I thought the listing was sorted alphabetically.

Comment: When I use Firefox to simply copy the request, the Cookie header is not sent again.

Comment: When copying the request into a `fetch` command (you can do this in the context menu of the request line), invocation will automatically add the Cookie header and the response has status 200 (and contains data, retrievable by `const response = await fetch(...); const data = await response.json();`).

Comment: Oh wow, you're absolutely right! Using fetch does the trick. I guess it has something to do with promises (I'm not too familiar with them...). 

I'm not using stack overflow too often, sooo - can you provide this as an answer, and I'll mark it as solved by you?

Comment: Okay, and - do you have any idea how to do something similar as fetch in python? ^-^'

Comment: Please include all necessary messages and data as text, not as pictures. Also, include code necessary to reproduce the issue in the question itself, not just as a link that will go stale as soon as you fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response `security_notAuthenticated` indicates, that your way of repeating the request omits some authentication-related information.

When I repeat the request, using Mozilla Firefox's "Resend" or "Edit and resend" function, the `Cookie` header is not sent with the request. Although it occurs in the editable header list when using "Edit and resend" it's missing when watching the actual sent request. I'm not sure whether this is a feature or a bug.

When using Firefox's "Use as Fetch in Console" function, the header will automatically be included and you still have the ability to change the headers and the body. The `fetch` API is a web standard and some [introductory material about fetch can be found on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).

If you want to do custom requests, in the browser, `fetch` is a good option.
In other environments and languages you usually use some HTTP client (just search the web for "...your language... http request" or similar, you will find something).